# Connect my Google Sheet Macro with PostgresSQL

Tags: google-sheets

does anyone have information on how I can connect my Google Sheet macro with a PostgresSQL database?
I am currently making a connection but it gives me this error:

Información Error: Exception: Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol.

We want to download the information in a GoogleSheet file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include your code.